# meaning of a specific if-statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

What is the different meaning of the if-statement ( if(condition **->** condition) ) to the regular if-statement ( if(condition **=** condition)) ?

looking up for the meaning without success.

```
if ($erg->num_rows) {
    echo "<p>Daten vorhanden: Anzahl ";
    echo $erg->num_rows;
```

Comment: `->` is object member access.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php and http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with OOP concepts in PHP, then you will be able to understand what is going on here, else I recommend you to firstly get your hands dirty with OOP in PHP

Here `$erg->num_rows` is not a condition. `->` operator is used to access any attribute of the pointing class instance.

In simple words, this line:

```
if ($erg->num_rows)
```

checks if the number of rows is greater than zero (*as suggested by the variable name*), if yes then the following code will be executed.

Because `0` is `false` and any other number is `true`. That means if `$erg->num_rows` returns `0` then condition will be evaluated to `false` and if it returns value that is not `0`, then condition will be evaluated to `true`.

`->` operator has nothing to do with `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

**Example:**

```
<?php

class Erg {

  public $num_rows; // class property

  public function setNumRows( $val ) { // class function
      $this->num_rows = $val;
  } 
}

// create object of class Erg
$erg = new Erg();

// set value of num_rows property to 0
$erg->setNumRows( 0 );
echo $erg->num_rows; // access num_rows property using '->'

// set value of num_rows property to 1
$erg->setNumRows( 1 );
echo $erg->num_rows; // access num_rows property using '->'

?>
```